# Incomplete Clone Using Git-Svn

Tags: git-svn

I have an Svn repository at http://svn.domain.com/project that is structured as follows:

```
trunk/
  build_file_1.xml
  build_file_2.xml
  project_root/
branches/
  cc2.10/
  cc3.00/
  ..
  cc3.5/
  jira-labs-39/
tags/
  studio-2.10.0.0/
  studio-2.10.0.1/
  ...
  studio-3.4.1.0/
```

I want to clone the trunk and branches, but I'm only getting the trunk and the first branch.  I'm using this command to clone:

```
git svn clone http://svn.domain.com/project working-dir --trunk=trunk --branches=branches --prefix=svn/
```

What I end up with is this:

```
$ git br -r
svn/cc2.10
svn/trunk
```

I need to do some work on one of the other branches, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

I just noticed the following error at the end of the output stream:

```
merge-base 7c552afeaba8194137acb95e642a2222db801dad c40b790b610dc43da93de5328832b1f852a14ef2: command returned error: 1
```

I assume that error is aborting the clone before it's complete, but I can't find any reference to the error or what it means in order to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem appears to be in the fact that Git-Svn tries to being cloning from one directory above the requested start point. Using the `--no-minimize` option fixed that.

```
git svn clone http://svn.domain.com/project working-dir -s --no-minimize-url
```